# Prometheus for monitoring docker containers on multi servers

Tags: docker, monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I am new in prometheus.

I want to monitor all docker containers inside many servers. 
The case is like this:

1. I have 3 servers -> server A, B, and C (all running with Ubuntu).
2. Each server has many docker containers for difference project.
3. I will add one server (server D) and I want to install Prometheus on
   this server.

My questions:

1. is it possible, If I want to install Prometheus to server D and
   monitor all docker containers in server A, B, and C?
2. is it possible if I want to monitor all containers sorted by
   project? for example I use Gravana dashborad. Can I have one gravana
   dashboard for each project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very nice project which I found and now I can solved my problem.

I used dockprom which created by stefan you can visit this [github link](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom) .

These are streps that I used:

I use one server as a master (I deploy dockprom project on this server).

There are two ways to monitor another server by using this project;

1. You can only deploy cadvisor and nodeexporter containers on another
   server then connect to prometheus master, but you need to add some configurations.
2. The second way which I used was more simple, I deploy dockprom to
       all servers then I added datasource on master server (I filled the
       data source IP with IP server which I want to monitor plus
       prometheus port).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Prometheus can monitor them. You'll need to let Prometheus know what's running where, either by hand in the config or by using service discovery such as Consul.

On the Grafana side if you've got Prometheus labels setup to distinguish the projects, then the Grafana templates feature will let you do that.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I have added the answer too. 
Thank you

Comment: @brian-brazil as you said consul is 
[https://prometheus.io/blog/2015/06/01/advanced-service-discovery/#discovery-with-consul](https://prometheus.io/blog/2015/06/01/advanced-service-discovery/#discovery-with-consul) as i guess and what is the other way?